# Maven project cannot find junit

Tags: scala, maven, junit

I am writing a simple project using maven, scala and junit.

One problem I found is that my tests cannot find org.junit.framework.Test. The test file:

```
import org.junit.framework.Test

class AppTest {
  @Test
  def testOK() = assertTrue(true)

  @Test
  def testKO() = assertTrue(false)
}
```

returns error:

```
[WARNING].....    error: object junit is not a member of package org
[WARNING] import org.junit.framework.Test
[WARNING]            ^
```

I did have junit added as a dependency and it clearly sits inside my repository.

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Can someone tell me what causes this?

Many thanks

Comment: Is the test file actually in the test folders? If not, the scope of test will mess everything up. Try removing the scope tag and see if that helps. The rest of the dependency in the POM looks fine from here. Secondly, what package is your AppTest class in?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, the test code is in the test folder. The file is in a package com.mycompany.myservice.

Comment: Do you actually have the junit .jars in your .m2 folder? I think it's ~/.m2/repositories by default.

Answer (score 2):

As @nico_ekito says, your import is incorrect, and should be `org.junit.Test`.

But this doesn't explain your problem:

```
[WARNING].....    error: object junit is not a member of package org
[WARNING] import org.junit.framework.Test
[WARNING]            ^
```

So it can't find org.junit. This means that org.junit isn't in the classpath when you're compiling the tests. So either your dependency tree is screwed up, or the actual jar is.

Try

```
mvn dependency:list
```

This should result in something like:

```
[INFO] The following files have been resolved:
[INFO]    junit:junit:jar:4.8.1:test
```

Ensure that you've got no other junit libraries being resolved. If everything looks ok, check the contents of your junit jar. It should contain the class org.junit.Test. If it doesn't, you've got a corrupted repo, or you're not looking in the right place. The easiest way to know this is to use:

```
mvn dependency:copy-dependencies
```

which creates target/dependency with a copy of the dependencies. You can look at the jar there.

Answer (score 1):

The package for the `Test` class in JUnit 4.8.1 is `junit.framework.Test` and not `org.junit.framework.Test`.

Comment: Close, but no cigar. It's actually org.junit.Test. See http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Test.html. And it doesn't answer why org.junit isn't found.

Comment: I'm not sure, but the doc that you indicate is for JUnit 3.8, not 4.8. If you look at the JUnit jar (http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Cjunit%7Cjunit%7C4.8.1%7Cjar), you'll see that the import is junit.framework.Test.

Comment: You're right about the link, try http://kentbeck.github.com/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/Test.html instead. The annotation @Test which is the one used by the OP is org.junit.Test.

Comment: @MatthewFarwell I don't want to insist (but I do ;-), if you look at the v4.8.1 tag, the Test class is in the package `junit/framework` https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/blob/r4.8.1/src/main/java/junit/framework/Test.java. In the latest (master branch), the Test class is not under the org.junit package : https://github.com/KentBeck/junit/tree/master/src/main/java/org/junit

Comment: The Test class that you're pointing to is an INTERFACE which was used in JUnit 3. The ANNOTATION which is used by the OP is in org.junit, and has been since 4.0. And it is under the link that you posted. At the bottom. Under Test.java.

Comment: Ah ok, really sorry. I was focusing for the "framework" subpackage !!